# Would Dual boot with Ubuntu 16.04.01 LTS 64 bit and 32 bit clash?

Tags: dual-boot, 64-bit, 32-bit

I'm really new to the world of Ubuntu and Linux and have an Ubuntu 16.04.01 LTS 64 bit on my machine as I plan to upgrade my RAM later on.

Now I found out that several apps and games require multiple xxx:i386 libraries. I tried to follow down the rabbit hole of the dependencies to a point where the system tried to remove amd64 libs.

To avoid damaging the 64 bit system, would it be possible to install 32 bit version of Ubuntu alongside the 64 bit version or would it cause some kind of clash between the 2 systems?

Comment: Favour returned! You're an 8-rep user already!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can boot any multitude of Linux OSes together as long as you give them each their own `/` partition and they all use GRUB2

In the case of Ubuntu 64 and 32-bit I would keep the `/home` partition in common as long as you use different users *in the unlikely case* that applications running on both systems use different configuration files. (so not the OS would be the problem, but some applications might be...)

E.G. admin64 & user64 and admin32 & user32

That way you can still access the user files of the other users transparently, whereas the config files are kept separate.